# Using pyodbc to import column name with non alphanumeric characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-access, pyodbc

I'm currently trying to use pyodbc to read columns from Microsoft Access into python. One of the columns has a + sign in it. How would I go about selecting this column and then printing a row from the column. Currently my code looks something like this:

```
crsr.execute("select CompoundKey, Q1Mass, Q3Mass, +veDP, CE from Conditions")
for row in crsr:
    print("Q1 Mass: %.3f" % row.Q1Mass)
```

So I'd like to be able to import +veDP and then print the rows of that column.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to have Access SQL deal with spaces and "funny characters" in  object names is to use square brackets, e.g.,

```python
crsr.execute("select CompoundKey, Q1Mass, Q3Mass, [+veDP] AS posDP, CE from Conditions")
```

**Edit:**

Be aware that Access allows us to specify a "Caption" for a given field ...

[image: DesignView.png]

... and when we look at the table in Datasheet View it appears that the field is named [+veDP] ...

[image: DatasheetView.png]

... when in fact the field name is actually [posDP].

Comment: I tried that and got this error message:   
  crsr.execute("select [+veDP] as posDP from Conditions")
pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: `print([x.column_name for x in crsr.columns("Conditions")])`. Do you see `'+veDP'` in the list? If not, then it is not actually a column name. (It may be the Caption of a column.)

Comment: Thanks! That helped!